# Ractive.js template looping

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I'm making an ajax call and pull down the total number of pages:

```
$.get(path, function( data ) {
    ractive.set({
    'articles' : data.articles,
    'totalpages' : data.totalpages
    });
});
```

Is there any way I can render the pagination buttons from the total page count? Something like (assuming totalpages = 4):

```
{{#if loop totalpages times:num}}
  <a href="#">{{num}}</a> | 
{{/if}}
```

Would output

```
<a href="#">1</a> | <a href="#">2</a> | <a href="#">3</a> | <a href="#">4</a>
```

I had a look at Mustache docs, but Mustache isn't quite the same.

Thanks,
Rob

Comment: You can transform the number of pages into an array, and use map on it

    [1,2,3,4].map(function(n){return <a href="#">n</a>});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a computed property in your component or ractive instance:

```
computed: {
    total: 'new Array(${totalPages})'               
}
```

And then use the `:index` (or whatever you want) to alias the index on the each:

```
{{#each total:index}}
<a href="#">{{index+1}}</a>
{{/each}}
```

**Edit**: Above `total` computed property is Ractive shorthand for:

```
computed: {
    total: function(){
        return new Array(this.get('totalPages'));
    }   
}
```

Comment: I had no idea about the computed property - brilliant! thanks :) I'm a little confused about scope here. By invoking a new Array here - in the way with the quotes (still confused by that) -  does that new Array become globally scoped? Or, will it get erased each time the data updates (Im passing the total number of pages down with each ajax call)

Comment: Clarified the computed shorthand syntax. It will get replaced each time the data updates (though ractive will reuse the DOM nodes).

Comment: Ahha! Thanks :) I get it now :)